# Store multiple form input values in local storage in JavaScript in the form of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, set, local-storage

I am trying to save input values submitted through form into local storage in the form of the array, but once the form is submitted again, the saved value in local storage gets changed with the new submitted value as the

```
function bookDetails(bookName,bookAuthor,bookType) {
    this.name = bookName;
    this.author = bookAuthor;
    this.type = bookType;
}

let libraryForm = document.getElementById("bookForm");
libraryForm.addEventListener("submit", libraryBooksDetails);

function libraryBooksDetails(e,index) {
    
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("The book details have been submitted");
    let bookName = document.getElementById("bookName").value;
    let bookAuthor = document.getElementById("author").value;
    let bookType;
    let fiction = document.getElementById("Fiction"); 
    let programming = document.getElementById("ComputerProgramming");
    let personal = document.getElementById("PersonalDevelopement");
    
    if(fiction.checked){
        bookType = fiction.value;
    }
    else if(programming.checked){
        bookType = programming.value;
    }
    else if(personal.checked){
        bookType = personal.value;
    }
// BookDetails Object
    let book = new bookDetails(bookName,bookAuthor,bookType);
    
    let bookData = ""
    bookData = bookData || [];
    let nameOfBooks = bookData.concat(bookName)
    // let nameOfBooks = bookData
    // nameOfBooks.push(book.bookName);
    localStore.setItem("books",JSON.stringify(nameOfBooks))
    console.log(book);

    let display = new Display()
    display.add(book);
    display.clear();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The two lines where you set bookData value doesn't seem to have a clear purpose. You are essentially writing `let bookData = "" || []`. Check you variable names and add more console logs at various places inside the code to figure out where the data is changing.

Comment: What is the question? Please respond by [editing (changing) your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70742125/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I have written the question that I want to save the value submitted through the form in the local storage.
But value stored gets replaced with the value if a new form is submitted

Comment: @Muge 
`let bookData = ""`
It was done to just declare a variable with this name so I can use it to store input value in local storage but it works fine.
The issue is not this code but the issue i want to store all input values which are submitted through a form which this code is not doing as it replaces the old stored value with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question completely because you are setting the value `let book = new bookDetails` but that is not what you are storing in local storage.

```js
// First time bookData value is set, this is always an empty string
let bookData = "";

// Since empty string is a falsey value, bookData value is re-set to an empty array
bookData = bookData || [];

// nameOfBooks is initialised as an array with one value of bookName
let nameOfBooks = bookData.concat(bookName);

// books key in local storage is a stringified array with one item
localStore.setItem("books", JSON.stringify(nameOfBooks));
```

`localStorage.setItem(key, value)` will always replace the existing value at that key. If you want to append to the stored value, first get the value and parse it before appending the new value.

```js
const oldValue = localStorage.getItem('books');
const parsed = JSON.parse(oldValue);
const newValue = parsed.concat(nameOfBooks);
localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(newValue));
```